# help to find the bug for calculating inverse kinematic using jacobian

Tags: inverse-kinematics, jacobian, python

I am calculating inverse kinematic for 5dof robotic arm using Jacobian matrix (first time). i used following formulas to do my calculation and also implemented in my code.

[image]
[image]
[image]

for more information please follow this link --> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SefTCXrpL8U&t=872s

I am not understanding what I am doing wrong. I am getting the wrong theta values and while loop is running maximum two times, it does not matter which values I give as x, y, z.
- I have searched, how others have calculated their Jacobian matrices. but still could not find my mistake.

please help me to debug my code. I might be doing some silly mistake.
This is a code for calculating forward kinematics

```
class Fkine:
    def __init__(self, PT):
        """ Initialize the DH parameters for forward kinematics
            DH peramteres columes should be DH = [theta alpha  r  d]
        """
        if not isinstance(PT, list):
            print("[ERROR] dh parameter should be matrix {}".format(PT))
        if not np.shape(PT)[1] == 4:
            print("[ERROR] enter proper dh parameter {}".format(PT))

        self.PT = np.array(PT)


    def homog_trans_matrix(self, row_num):

        cos_theta_n = np.cos(self.PT[row_num][0])
        sin_theta_n = np.sin(self.PT[row_num][0])

        cos_alpha_n = np.cos(self.PT[row_num][1])
        sin_alpha_n = np.sin(self.PT[row_num][1])

        r_n = self.PT[row_num][2]
        d_n = self.PT[row_num][3]

        homog_trans_matrix = [
            [cos_theta_n, -sin_theta_n * cos_alpha_n, sin_theta_n * sin_alpha_n, r_n * cos_theta_n],
            [sin_theta_n, cos_theta_n * cos_alpha_n, -cos_theta_n * sin_alpha_n, r_n * sin_theta_n],
            [0, sin_alpha_n, cos_alpha_n, d_n],
            [0, 0, 0, 1],
        ]
        return np.matrix(homog_trans_matrix)


    def fk(self):
        """ function to generate forward kinematic from DH parameters
            by multiplying homogeneous transformation matrix Hn = H_0 * H_1 * ....H_n-1
        """
        Hn = []

        # taking the number of rows from the DH parameters
        for i in range(np.shape(self.PT)[0]):
            H = self.homog_trans_matrix(i)

            if i == 0:
                Hn = H

            else:
                Hn = np.dot(Hn, H)

        return Hn

def get_jacobian(fkine_obj, PT):
    Hn = fkine_obj.fk()
    # print(Hn)
    R0_0 = [
        [0.],
        [0.],
        [1.]
    ]
    D0_n = Hn[:, 3][:-1]

    upper_part = np.cross(R0_0, D0_n, axis=0)
    # print(upper_part)

    for i in range(np.shape(PT)[0] - 1):
        H0_i = fkine_obj.homog_trans_matrix(i)

        # accessing 3rd column of the matrix and removing last row
        R0_i = H0_i[:, 2][:-1]

        # accessing 4th column of the matrix and removing last row
        D0_i = H0_i[:, 3][:-1]

        next_col = np.cross(R0_i, np.subtract(D0_n, D0_i), axis=0)

        upper_part = np.concatenate([upper_part, next_col], axis=1)

    return upper_part
def main():

    THETA_1 = 0.1
    THETA_2 = 90.
    THETA_3 = 0.1
    THETA_4 = 0.1
    THETA_5 = 0.1

    L_1 = 33.  # mm 3.3cm
    L_2 = 105.  # mm 10.5cm
    L_3 = 98.  # mm 9.8cm
    L_4 = 27.  # mm 2.7cm
    L_5 = 65.  # mm 6.5cm

    # DH parameter table for my robotic arm
    PT = [
        [math.radians(THETA_1), math.radians(90.0), 0, L_1],
        [math.radians(THETA_2), 0, L_2, 0],
        [math.radians(THETA_3), 0, L_3, 0],
        [math.radians(THETA_4) + math.radians(90.0), math.radians(90.0), 0, 0],
        [math.radians(THETA_5), 0, 0, L_4 + L_5]
    ]

    x_dst = 1.
    y_dst = 1.
    z_dst = 1.

    while 180. >= math.degrees(PT[0][0]) >= 0. \
            and 180. >= math.degrees(PT[1][0]) >= 0. \
            and 180. >= math.degrees(PT[2][0]) >= 0. \
            and 180. >= math.degrees(PT[3][0]) >= 0. \
            and 180. >= math.degrees(PT[4][0]) >= 0.:

        fk_5d = fk.Fkine(PT)
        jacobian = get_jacobian(fk_5d, PT)

        jacobian_inv = np.linalg.pinv(jacobian)
        current_cord = fk_5d.fk()[:, 3][:-1]

        theta_dots = jacobian_inv.dot([
            [x_dst],
            [y_dst],
            [z_dst],
        ])

        PT[0][0] += theta_dots.item(0) / 100
        PT[1][0] += theta_dots.item(1) / 100
        PT[2][0] += theta_dots.item(2) / 100
        PT[3][0] += theta_dots.item(3) / 100
        PT[4][0] += theta_dots.item(4) / 100
```

sorry for the bad indentation, I do now know how to do it.

thank you very much in advance